# Given StartDate and EndDate, return matching row in Dates table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need a formula for a single cell. I want this formula to tell me whether the given StartDate and EndDate match any rows in the problem dates table:

```
Start Date    End Date     Any problems?
1/1/2020      1/7/2020     -need formula-
```

Here's the problem dates table:

```
Date          Problem
1/7/2020      You can't select this date
1/1/1990      This date is in the past
```

I want my cell to say "You can't select this date" because it found 1/7/2020 from the problem dates table between the given start date and end date.

Comment: First question: Are you trying to see if all dates between start and end will match a row in the problems table? Second question: What if multiple dates in that range are found in the problems table? Does it need to display an error for every date matched?

Comment: First question: yes, I want to know if every date between StartDate and EndDate will match a row in the problems table. Second question: if multiple dates are found, I want the first match (or any one of the matches - I just need to know that there was a problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `INDEX`/`AGGREGATE` functions:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(G:G,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($F$2:$F$4)/((A2<=$F$2:$F$4)*(B2>=$F$2:$F$4))),1)),"")
```

or `LOOKUP`:

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/((A2<=$F$2:$F$4)*(B2>=$F$2:$F$4)),$G$2:$G$4),"")
```

[image]

Comment: I can't thank you enough!! This is exactly what I needed